# PayPal.ConnectionException: Invalid HTTP response: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.sandbox.paypal.com'

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Can anyone please help me find out solution to this error ?

[image: PayPal.ConnectionException]

Comment: It sounds like your application isn't able to find that web address.  Are you able to connect to that address manually from that machine?

Comment: @David - No, it keeps on saying "The server at api.sandbox.paypal.com is taking too long to respond". To my surprise, I had created few apps following the same procedure, previously. They all are working.

Comment: Maybe the API is just currently down?

Comment: Well, don't you think, in that case it should have impact on previously created apps

Comment: As david already pointed out, this looks like a DNS issue. 
Are you still experiencing problems? 
A manual connection to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com will fail, btw. you can try and load https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment in the browser - which should return a HTTP 401 return (blank page) because you're not sending an access token.